# cfBuilder - working with javascript, CSS, HTML etc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I moved from Dreamweaver to cfBuilder about 12 months ago, and now work almost exclusively in cfBuilder.  On the whole, I find it very good.

One thing I don't like though is that it isn't very good for editing Javascript, CSS and HTML (great for CFML though).  I remember when reviewing Eclipse some time ago that you can setup Eclipse (using plugins ??) too work with different languages, such as CSS, HTML, SQL, Java, PHP .. whatever..

I assume this can be done with cfBuilder as well...  how do I setup these different eclipse environments in cfbuilder?

Many Thanks in advance

EDIT: for example.. can I load this eclipse IDE into cfBuilder?.  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/indigosr1

Comment: CFBuilder is built on Eclipse, so you should be able to add whatever other Eclipse plug-ins you like. [Aptana](http://aptana.com) is one that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That to me looks like a complete Eclipse install with embedded plug-ins, rather than just a plug-in.  So it would be to Eclipse what CFBuilder is to Eclipse; so you'd install it as well / instead of CFB, not as a plug-in within it.

Your question probably needs retagging: it's nothing to do with ColdFusion (which is the server end of things), and more to do with just "Eclipse" than "ColdFusion Builder", because the question is more "how does the Eclipse plug-in architecture work".

Perhaps the best way to start understanding how Eclipse plug-ins work would ebt o take a step back and have a look at vanilla Eclipse, and have a look at how CFEclipse installs (instructions here: http://trac.cfeclipse.org/wiki/InstallingCfeclipse). This'll give you an idea about how Eclipse plug-ins work, and they work exactly the same way if your Eclipse install happens to have CFB wrapped around it.

I'm not sure if that suggestion is any help, but it is how I would approach solving this problem if I had it.